# Counting Iterations

Tags: computational-complexity, floating-point

> How many multiplications are performed when the 
>   following code fragment is executed? Express your answers in terms of $n$, where $n \geq 10$.
>
> ```
> for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
>   for(j= i+1; j < n; j++)
>     a[i][j] = a[i][j]*0.001;
> ```

With a little trial and error I can see that $8n - 36$ seems to work when $n \geq 10$, but I was curious on how to derive it. I understand that you get a double summation and simplify in terms of $N$, but the inner loop is throwing me off as I've never done double summation with an extra variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work it out from the inside summation.

$\sum_{i=0}^7 \sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1} 1  = \sum_{i=0}^7  (n-1-i) = 8(n-1)-(0+\cdots+7)$.

Comment: Hmm, didn't think to subtract i from n - 1 when I was attempting it. It makes sense algebraically, but how did you know to subtract i from n - 1? Upvoted.

Comment: If the loop has values $a,a+1,....,b$ then the number of different values is given by $b-a+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  As is often the case in math, you take it apart.  The inner loop starts at $j=i+1$ and executes through $j=n-1$.  How many values of $j$ is that?  You are allowed to express it in terms of $i$ and $n$.  Then you need to sum this expression over $i=0$ through $i=7$